# Getters y setters en javascript

Tags: javascript

me estoy adentrando al mundo de la programación.Me esta costando trabajo entender los getters y setters, entiendo que son para validacion de datos, pero el problema esque pasando la seccion de objetos viene clases y por lo que veo solo usan los getters.

Exactamente los getters son para obtener datos de una funcion? No simplemente la funcion hace eso?
Me podrian explicar con ejemplos de la vida real para entender mejor?
Aprecio la ayuda

Comment: Hola Joseamica, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así conseguir tu primera medalla). Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes probar a leer [esta respuesta a una pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131147/pregunta-sobre-metodo-get-en-javascript/131153#131153)

Answer (score 1):

Los getters y setters son parte de la interfaz pública, que mediante métodos públicos te permiten modificar u obtener datos privados, por ejemplo en una clase "Libro" un atributo es editorial y por encapsulamiento es privado(sólo accesible dentro de la misma clase), el método setEditorial te permitirá acceder al atributo privado y modificarlo, getEditorial también accederá al atributo y lo regresará.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function Libro(editorial){
    const that = this;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    return {
        setEditorial: function(editorial){
            that.editorial = editorial;
        },
        getEditorial: function() {
            return that.editorial;
        }
    };
}
const libro = Libro("ejemplo editorial");
console.log(libro.getEditorial());//mediante un método público se accede a un atributo privado
console.log(libro.editorial);//undefined porque no se puede acceder a un atributo privado desde afuera de la clase
libro.setEditorial("cambio de editorial");
console.log(libro.getEditorial());//imprime "cambio de editorial"

//Sólo para que veas qué contiene el objeto,
//verás que sólo son las funciones y no hay algún atributo editorial
console.log(libro);
```

Si ejecutas ese código verás una salida:

`ejemplo editorial
undefined
cambio de editorial`

`undefined` corresponde a esta línea: `console.log(libro.editorial);` ya que el atributo es privado.

Sólo los getters y setters pueden acceder a la editorial pues en el `return` se regresan sólo los métodos públicos que sí tienen acceso al atributo editorial gracias a `that`.

**Notas:** Usé un *closure* para este ejemplo pero no es lo más recomendable, ya que cada función ocupa memoria, pero el objetivo era mostrar la interfaz pública.

La razón de `const that = this` es por el contexto en el que se ejecutan las funciones públicas que deben hacer referencia a `this` pero de la función Libro.

```js
function Libro(editorial){
    const that = this;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    return {
        setEditorial: function(editorial){
            that.editorial = editorial;
        },
        getEditorial: function() {
            return that.editorial;
        }
    };
}
const libro = Libro("ejemplo editorial");
libro.editorial = "nueva editorial";
console.log(libro.editorial + " --- " + libro.getEditorial());
   
//Sólo para que veas qué contiene el objeto,
//verás que sólo son las funciones y un atributo editorial, diferente al definido en la función Libro
console.log(libro);
```

Como puedes ver imprime primero `libro.editorial` y después `libro.getEditorial()` y SON DIFERENTES, esto es porque al poner `libro.editorial = "nueva editorial"` se crea otro atributo diferente al que está en la función Libro.

Comment: Por último y esto como simple recomendación (por ello no está en la respuesta), si quieres aprender programación orientada a objetos uses lengajes como JAVA que se especializa en ese paradigma, ya que como puedes ver con javascript tienes que hacer cosas un poco raras como los closures, prototypes lo del contexto `const that = this` y demás, aunque ES6 ya implementa la palabra reservada `class` pero no te da lo que java, por ejemplo para hacer privado a editorial usé closures, con java simplemente hubiera puesto `private String editorial`, es un poco más explícito.

Comment: Sólo para agregar, Javascript utiliza objetos más no es un lenguaje orientado a objetos segun la POO (carece de herencia [EC5], clases [EC5] y encapsulamiento). Javascript está orientado en prototipos, así que en lugar de emular el comportamiento de un paradigma en otro lo mejor los conceptos de cada paradigma y explotarlos. Por ejemplo en Javascript la cadena de prototipado puede expresar relaciones más complejas entre objetos que no se pueden realizar en POO como la herencia multiple (sí se puede con traits y mecanismos no obstante no es tan facil como su contraparte en prototipos)

Answer (score 0):

Todas las funciones crean su propio alcanze, por lo cual nadie fuera de este puede acceder a las variables `declaradas` en él. Para combatir esto, viene el getter que nos permite visualizar las propiedades y el setter que nos permite modificarla.

El `getter` solamente retorna la propiedad y por eso podemos obtenerla.

El `setter` solamente recibe un parámetro y lo asigna a la propiedad.

```js
function data() {
 this.safe = true; // propiedad
 var that = this; // Guardamos el contexto de data
 this.getter = () => that.safe;
 this.setter = newSafe => { that.safe = newSafe; };
}

    var b = new data(); // Instanciamos el constructor

    console.log(b.getter()); // Sirve para obtener
    b.setter("Cambiado"); // Sirve para cambiar
    console.log(b.getter()); // Volvemos obtener para ver el cambio
```