# Pregunta sobre metodo get en javascript

Tags: javascript, clase

Una pregunta, de que me sirve externalizar una propiedad, he creado una propiedad total con el metodo get, pero para que es neecsario? Ya que haciendo un metodo lo puedo llamar igual con () y me retornara lo que yo quiera, en lugar de get total() hago total() y ya, no veo mucho la novedad del metodo get

```js
class Factura {
  constructor(divisa, nombre, importe, IVA = importe * .1) {
    this._divisa = divisa;
    this._nombre = nombre;
    this._importe = importe;
    this._IVA = IVA;
  }

  presentacion (){
    return ' La factura ' + this._nombre + ' tiene un importe de ' + this._importe + ' ' + this._divisa + ' y con el IVA, se queda en '
  }
  get total(){
    return this._importe + this._IVA;
  }
  // totalDescuento(){
  //   return this._importe + this._IVA -
  // }
}

let factura1 = new Factura('eur', 'Transportes Chemita', 300);
let factura2 = new Factura('eur', 'Transportes Fran', 600);
let factura3 = new Factura('eur', 'Transportes Ailyn', 900);
let factura4 = new Factura('eur', 'Transportes alvaro', 9000);
let factura5 = new Factura('eur', 'Transportes carlos', 9200);
let factura6 = new Factura('eur', 'Transportes pepito', 9100);

document.write(factura1.presentacion() + factura1.total + ' eur' + '<br>');
document.write(factura2.presentacion() + factura2.total + ' eur' + '<br>');
document.write(factura3.presentacion() + factura3.total + ' eur' + '<br>');
document.write(factura4.presentacion() + factura4.total + ' eur' + '<br>');
document.write(factura5.presentacion() + factura5.total + ' eur' + '<br>');
document.write(factura6.presentacion() + factura6.total + ' eur' + '<br>');
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es interesante. Quizá [este artículo](https://nemisj.com/why-getterssetters-is-a-bad-idea-in-javascript/) pueda ser la base de una posible respuesta.

Comment: que diferencia hay con respecto a tu pregunta anterior? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130858/pregunta-sobre-metodos-y-clases-en-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente lo que te aportan los métodos `get` y `set` es poder establecer lógica a la hora de establecer y recuperar valores de una propiedad manteniendo la sintaxis de propiedades del objeto:

```
// Para recuperar valor
var valor = instancia.nombrePropiedad;
// Para establecer valor
instancia.nombrePropiedad = valor;
```

Imagina que tienes un tipo `Persona` con una propiedad `nombreCompleto` que devuelve el nombre completo de la persona (nombre + apellidos) y permite igualmente establecer este valor:

```js
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, apellidos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
  }

  get nombreCompleto(){
    return (this.nombre ? this.nombre + ' ' : '')
      + (this.apellidos ? this.apellidos : '');
  }
  
  set nombreCompleto(value){
    if (typeof value === 'string'){
      var parts = value.split(' ');
      this.nombre = parts[0];
      this.apellidos = parts.slice(1).join(' ');
    }
  }
  
}

var foo = new Persona('Asier', 'Villanueva Rodilla');
console.log(foo, foo.nombreCompleto);
foo.nombreCompleto='Pedro Picapiedra';
console.log(foo, foo.nombreCompleto);
```

Como ves tanto para recuperar como para establecer el valor se utiliza la sintaxis `foo.nombreCompleto`.

Hasta ECMAScript 5 tendrías que crear para hacer esto dos métodos: uno para recuperar el valor y otro para establecerlo.

```js
function Persona(nombre, apellidos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.getNombreCompleto = function(){
      return (this.nombre ? this.nombre + ' ' : '')
      + (this.apellidos ? this.apellidos : '');
    }
    this.setNombreCompleto = function(value){
      if (typeof value === 'string'){
        var parts = value.split(' ');
        this.nombre = parts[0];
        this.apellidos = parts.slice(1).join(' ');
      }
    }
}

var foo = new Persona('Asier', 'Villanueva Rodilla');
console.log({nombre: foo.nombre, apellidos: foo.apellidos}, foo.getNombreCompleto());
foo.setNombreCompleto('Pedro Picapiedra');
console.log({nombre: foo.nombre, apellidos: foo.apellidos}, foo.getNombreCompleto());
```

Aquí utilizarías el método `getNombreCompleto` para recuperar el valor y el método `setNombreCompleto` para establecerlo.

De esta forma abstraes los detalles de implementación internos del desarrollador que hace uso del api externa del objeto.

Quizás el caso más práctico sea cuando quieres añadir una validación a una propiedad ya existente. Con el método anterior tendrías que dejar la variable que almacena el valor como privada y crear un método para establecer el valor que realice la validación (como el `setNombreCompleto`). Esto obligaría a modificar todas las líneas de código que establecieran el valor de esta propiedad. Mediante un método `set` podrías añadir esa validación interna sin necesidad de cambiar todo el código que hace uso de la api externa.

Comment: En `ECMAScript 5.1` se pueden definir `getters/setters` en un constructor (_o "clase"_), solo que es necesario utilizar [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperties). [Aquí un ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/pLuLr4a7/)

Comment: Cierto @Marcos, sí que estaba disponible a través de `defineProperties`

Answer (score 1):

Los getter/setters son muy utilizados principalmente por los frameworks y librerias debido que hacen mas fácil el patron [Binding o observable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) donde los setters te permiten intervenir al momento de asignar el valor a la propiedad para realizar otra operación ademas de la asignación:

```js
var persona ={
 nombre: null,
 apellido: null,
 get nombreCompleto(){
   return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
 },
 set nombreCompleto(value){
   var data = value.split(' ');
   this.nombre = data[0];
   this.apellido  = data[1];
   alert("se cambio el nombrea a " + this.nombreCompleto);
 }
};


persona.nombreCompleto = "Stack Overflow";
```

Nota como es posible recibir la notificación de cambio de nombre con una sintaxis limpia y común para todos: `persona.nombreCompleto = 'valor'`. Y se puede llevar aun mas lejos. Por ejemplo, al momento de asignar un valor a la propiedad `nombreCompleto` que también se edite un `input` relacionado a la propiedad:

```js
  var persona ={
     nombre: null,
     apellido: null,
     get nombreCompleto(){
       return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
     },
     set nombreCompleto(value){
       var data = value.split(' ');
       this.nombre = data[0];
       this.apellido  = data[1];

       // editamos el valor del input nombre-completo
       document.getElementById("nombre-completo").value = this.nombreCompleto;
     }
    };


    persona.nombreCompleto = "Stack Overflow";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      persona.nombreCompleto = "Einer Stack"
    }, 1000);
```

```html
Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre-completo" />
```

En cuanto a los setters ya esto serviría para procesar/formatear o limpiar la data antes de retornarla al codigo cliente. En C# los [get/set son muy utilizados por WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) por la facilidad que proveen al definir las propiedades.

Pero como siempre se ha dicho, tienes que encontrar el caso correcto para implementar los set/get, de lo contrario, mejor utilizar funciones/propiedades estandares.

Comment: Casi "clavamos" el ejemplo. Ya es casualidad :D

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Estaba escribiendo lo mismo en tu respuesta haha.